# Ruby on rails creating link to update mysql row

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have no clue how to do this.
I have an unordered list containing some list items.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>Lock</li>
    <li>Log off</li>
    <li>Restart</li>
    <li>Shutdown</li>
</ul>
```

I want to make all the list items clickable and when its clicked on it needs to add itself to the 'actions' row of the 'pc' model. (Pc.actions) I need help creating the link and how I can handle it in the pc_controller.

Comment: You need to clearify the question. I assume Pc is a model with an association has_many :actions ? Manually you could for example add methods in the controller that takes a params[] array with the id of the Pc and then add an action in one of several ways. Let me know if this is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've found what I wanted:

```
<li><%= link_to "Lock", pc_path(pc.id, pcAction: 'lock'), :method => :put %></li>
```